# How can I find out why a trivial Word add-in doesn't load?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word, vsto, add-in

I'm using a Macbook Pro with a clean install of Windows 8.1, Office Ultimate 2007 and Visual Studio Pro 2010. All are activated.

I begin Visual Studio and create a Word 2007 Application Add-in ("WordAddin1"). I then press F5 and Word is loaded. I check in Word Options -> Add-ins, and the WordAddin1 appears under "Inactive". Activating it via "COM Add-ins" results in the "Load Behaviour:" (displayed below the list of Add-ins available) becoming "Not loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM Add-in".

There is nothing in the event log pertaining to Office and Setting the environment variable VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS to 0 doesn't help.

Identical actions with identical versions of Office and Visual Studio on two other machines results in the "WordAddin1" being loaded and thus appearing under "Active" add-ins.

How can I debug this?

Comment: Share the code you have for `ThisAddIn.ThisAddIn_Startup`. You just need to set a breakpoint there to see what is happening.

Comment: There is no code in there; if I add some code (e.g. a message box), it never gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across the same problem, that it's very hard to find out why the loading of an addin fails.

In my case it was just a version mismatch of the addin-dll, but there could be more possibilities. The tool AddinSpy was very helpful for me for figuring out the exact error (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/AddInSpy/).

Also, you could enable the Fusion logs - if you are using .net to develop the addin, which is not quite clear from your question. You can find more information on the fusion log viewer here, it could provide valuable information if the .net runtime is not able to load your dll:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx